# thread_local shared_ptr object is causing sigsegv when destructing

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mingw, mingw-w64

I have a program, which is using `thread_local std::shared_ptr` to manage some objects that are mainly accessed thread-locally. However when the thread is joined and the thread local `shared_ptr` is destructing, there is always SIGSEGV when debugging if the program is compiled by MinGW (Windows 10). Here is a minimum code to reproduce the bug:

```
// main.cpp
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

void f() {
    thread_local std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(0);
}

int main() {
    std::thread th(f);
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

How to compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -o build\main.exe -std=c++17
```

Compiler version:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Run using gdb it will give SIGSEGV in new thread, when the main thread is waiting for `join()`. It works fine when compiled by gcc, clang (Linux) and MSVC (Windows).

I tried to debug and found that, a continuous segment of memory containing the thread local shared_ptr was erased to repeated `0xfeeefeee` before destruction when calling `RtlpWow64SetContextOnAmd64`. The frames:

```
RtlpWow64SetContextOnAmd64 0x00007ffd8f4deb5f
RtlpWow64SetContextOnAmd64 0x00007ffd8f4de978
SbSelectProcedure 0x00007ffd8f4ae2e0
CloseHandle 0x00007ffd8ce3655b
pthread_create_wrapper 0x00007ffd73934bac
_beginthreadex 0x00007ffd8e9baf5a
_endthreadex 0x00007ffd8e9bb02c
BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007ffd8ec87614
RtlUserThreadStart 0x00007ffd8f4c26a1
```

The assembly:

```
...
mov    %rax,(%rdi)
movdqu %xmm0,(%rsi)               ; <------ erased here
call   0x7ffd8f491920             ; <ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockShared>
mov    $0x1,%r9d
mov    0x30(%rsp),%rbx
...
```

later the shared_ptr is destructed, and when reading `0xfeeefeee` there is SIGSEGV.

I want to know that:

- Why MinGW (or Windows library?) is erasing the thread local storage before destruction? In my opinion erasing memory should only happen after the destruction. I notice that if `join()` is replaced by `detach()`, the program exits normally. Maybe `join()` did something to instruct the new thread to erase the storage?
- Is such behavior a violation of standard? I think the standard should forbid erasing the memory before destruction. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Mixing `thread_local` with a local variable is unusual use case. I guess `ptr` is destroyed at `f` end. I suggest moving the variable to the global scope. On the other hand, it implies a static local variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794640/6752050

Comment: Maybe of topic but 0xfeeefeee denotes a previously deallocated block. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values).

Comment: As said having a thread global variable as local seems strange, but also the fact that you want to make something that is threadlocal shared.  Since by definition a thread local variable should share its lifecycle with the lifecycle of the thread. And should not shareable by other threads. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @273K It doesn't work. ```thread_local std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
void f() {
    ptr = std::make_shared<int>(0);
}
```
will produce SIGSEGV when reading the same address `0xfeeefeee`

Comment: What mingw do you use? From msys2?

Comment: I can't reproduce on MSYS2 GCC (the MINGW64 one). Try it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer In fact I'm using `std::shared_ptr<std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource>` to control some memory allocation, but it may be off-topic here. I'm more curious about why this is happening.

Comment: Try run `gcc -v` or `g++ -v` and ensure the flag `--enable-tls` is set.

Comment: @273K Mingw-builds from https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/ , github page: https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases

Comment: Prefer using msys2 https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: @273K thank you I'll try later, it's late at night me here.

Comment: It is somewhat strange : From what I can make out (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource) your sope local variable will automatically also become a static variable and share the liftime with that of the thread.  Since this works in the two other compilers, this could be a bug. Have you checked the gcc bug list (I don't know where that is I usually use msvc, or sometimes clang)

Comment: Try on godbolt.org with different compiler versions, maybe if you select a newer one then the one you are using it is gone.

Comment: Doesn't compile on gcc 4.7.4, but from 4.8.1 it does compile and I see no issue : https://godbolt.org/z/qEGq4e9Pv. Side not, consider using std::make_unique (not related to this problem)

Comment: btw, I can reproduce this problem in Win 11, g++ (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0. It shown as ```Thread 5 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 15196.0x27dc]
0x00007ff7e54133f4 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() ()
(gdb) x/i $rbp
   0xfb957ff4b0:        loopne 0xfb957ff4a6```

Comment: Just an opinion, not an answer to your question, but I think you should shun `thread_local`. It's wrong for at least two reasons. First of all, `thread_local` only makes sense for statically allocated objects, and static allocation is the enemy of scalable, testable, and re-useable code. Second of all, it encourages the use of specialized threads. IMO, it's better to write in a style where, if something needs to be done, it should not matter which thread does it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow fyi _"...If thread_local is the only storage class specifier applied to a block scope variable, static is also implied...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a longstanding, open and known bug in mingw, see the corresponding issue with analyses and links on github: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/2519

Yes, this [violates the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47498351/3740047): it shouldn't crash.
Basically the order of destruction is incorrect, as you already suspected. The `0xfeeefeee` is the magic number used by `HeapFree()` to mark the freed memory. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/3740047).

To quote [lhmouse](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/2519#issuecomment-304155278):

> So here comes the rule of thumb: Don't use thread_local on GCC for MinGW targets.